Expo Router, navigating back one after navigating to "same" route multiple times doesn't go back 1
I am trying to revamp my routing w expo-router, where the same route is navigated to multiple times, by using router.push('/item/[id]').  However, when I navigate back() it goes back to the top of the stack instead of from item/2 to item/1
Any ideas?
directory:
item
    |__: _layout.tsx
    |__: [id].tsx


item/_layout.tsx:
<Stack>
    <Stack.Screen name="[id]" />
</Stack>

Inside the item component, there is an onPress event that gets captured like:
const handlePress = (label: string) => {
    router.push({
      pathname: `/pattern/[id]`, // I have also tried `/pattern/${label}`
      params: { id: label, from: from },
    });
  };

The back button is:
<Pressable
      onPress={router.back}
>
      <Icon />
</Pressable>


Try adding an anonymous function inside onPress prop:
<Pressable
  onPress={ ()=> router.back() }   
>
  <Icon />
</Pressable>

